# How to return array of structs from .Call to C shared library in R

Tags: r

How can I return a `struct` array from a `.Call` to a function in a C shared library and subsequently use that array in R?

For example:

```c
typedef struct{
    int    thing1;
    int    thing2;
    float  thing3;
    float  thing4;
    char   thing5;
    //... many more things of various simple types
} MY_STRUCT;

SEXP R_Calls_Me(SEXP args) {

    // Do stuff with args...

    // Create arrayOfMyStructs as what type??

    return arrayOfMyStructs;
}
```

What type is `arrayOfMyStructs` such that R can use it?

It seems like a common thing one would want to do, but I cannot find any examples of this in the documentation for writing R extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you create list (generic vector) with the components you want to return. In your case something like

```
SEXP res = PROTECT(allocVector(VECSXP, 5));
SET_VECTOR_ELT(res, 0, ScalarInteger(a.thing1));
SET_VECTOR_ELT(res, 1, ScalarInteger(a.thing2));
SET_VECTOR_ELT(res, 2, ScalarReal(a.thing3));
...
UNPROTECT(1)
return res;
```

It is also customary to assign names to the vector, e.g.:

```
const char *names[5] = { "thing1", "thing2", "thing3", "thing4", "thing5" };
SEXP sNames = PROTECT(allocVector(STRSXP, 5));
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) SET_STRING_ELT(res, i, mkString(names[i]));
setAttrib(res, R_NamesSymbol, sNames);
UNPROTECT(1);
```

Note that what you are describing is *not* an array but a structure. Arrays are typically much easier to pass as vectors.

Comment: Ultimately what I want is the ability to return an arbitrary number of these structures using a single call to the C function. Your example shows how to return one structure. Could I simply create a vector of vectors to accomplish this?

Comment: You could if that's convenient. Alternatively, if they are the same then you could use arrays (=vectors) - think of a data frame where columns are the structure records and rows are different structures. You would replace `SET_VECTOR_ELT(res, 0, ScalarInteger(a.thing1))` whith something like `SEXP t1 = allocVector(INTSXP, n); SET_VECTOR_ELT(res, 0, t1); int *t1i = INTEGER(t1); for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) t1i[i] = a[i].thing1;` In real life you would have single loop for all structure records, obviously.

Comment: I think your second approach makes the most sense for how I intend to use the returned data in R. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most natural way to do this is to use external pointers. You'll return a pointer to R and then your application code will manipulate that. A number of packages do this now, e.g., XML, h5r.

```
SEXP _h5R_make_ptr() {
    h5_holder* holder = (h5_holder*) Calloc(1, h5_holder);
    holder->id = 1;
    holder->is_file = 0;
    SEXP e_ptr = R_MakeExternalPtr(holder, R_NilValue, R_NilValue); 
    PROTECT(e_ptr);
    R_RegisterCFinalizerEx(e_ptr, h5R_finalizer, TRUE);
    UNPROTECT(1); 
    return e_ptr;
}
```

Comment: Except that you can't use those in R. External pointers are only useful for opaque structures that R has no way of accessing (see the question you can't "subsequently use it in R").